# How to make return type nullable using Optional<T> etc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, option-type, dto

I have the following method that returns `DemoDTO` and if it is not found, return exception.

```
public DemoDTO findShallowByUuid(UUID uuid) {
    return demoRepository.findShallowByUuid(uuid)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Not found"));
}
```

However, I want to let the method to return a nullable `DemoDTO` instead of throwing error. For this purpose, I converted its type and the related return types to `Optional<DemoDTO>` or `Optional<T>`, but it caused some problems regarding to the related DTO. After I updated the constructor parameters to `Optional<T>`, the other part of the app that using this DTO complained.

I am not sure converting to `Optional<T>` is a good idea or not. If it is a good idea, should I add another constructor to the `DemoDTO`? I am not sure if it is a good solution as it will also require some changes for the property types. Any idea?

Comment: What keeps you from changing your method to return `Optional`? Like `public Optional<DemoDTO> findShallowByUuid(UUID uuid) { return demoRepository.findShallowByUuid(uuid); }`

Comment: I tried, then I had to make lots of changes due to the necessary changes (converting to Optional in the DTO). Any suggestion?

Comment: Basically changing the return type to `Optional` is a good idea because that way you can let the calling code decide what to do with a "no result". The calling does not need to do a try-catch in order to find out whether there is a value for the given UUID. Sure, you need to change probably a lot of code. Another possibility: `ublic Optional<DemoDTO> findShallowByUuid(UUID uuid) { return demoRepository.findShallowByUuid(uuid).orElse(null);`. That way you avoid throwing the exception but you will return `null` and the calling code needs to check for null in order not to throw an `NullPointerExc

Comment: @jmizv Exactly!.. Thanks a lot, very elegant solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put my comment into an answer, this would be the most elegant way based on your requirements:

```
public DemoDTO findShallowByUuid(UUID uuid) {
    return demoRepository.findShallowByUuid(uuid).orElse(null);
}
```

But be sure that the calling code correctly handles `null` to avoid `NullPointerException`s.

Comment: Storing null in it ruins the whole idea of Optional type, imo

Comment: That is true but we don't store any `null` in an `Optional`.

Comment: In fact, it’s impossible to store a `null` in an `Optional`.